# how to convert unix timestamp to date+time for a given timzone

Tags: javascript, timestamp-with-timezone

In JavaScript, I have unix timestamp, how do i convert it to data+time for any given timezone, regardless of the local timezone? I am especially interested in US/eastern

Comment: `new Date()`, as described in the docs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date the parameter value can be an integer representing a unix timestamp. Then go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the property [`.toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) and set the desired timeZone

```
const unixTimestamp = 1548979200000; 
new Date(unixTimestamp).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "US/Eastern"})
```

Comment: that actually works, I thought it would be much  more complicated and requires moment.js, except  that "US/Eastern" doesn't work, I used "America/New_York"